# Difference in Time Series in Dygraphs

Tags: difference, dygraphs

I apologize for what is probably a really simple question, but I haven't been able to find an example to figure it out. I'm feeding simple CSV data to dygraphs where is row contains a different time, then values for several variables (at that time). I can get the data to plot just fine. However, I am wondering how to get dygraphs to perform functions with that data. Initially I'd just like to compute the difference between time steps of the various variables, but after that I'd like to do some additional things such as computing mean and standard deviations. I'm assuming I need to do the math within javascript code, but don't quite know how to do so.

So, if someone can provide a simple example of how to compute a difference between time steps of a variable and get dygraphs to plot that I'd really appreciate it. Here's what I mean...

If this were the data being provided.

1: DateTime, var1, var2
2: DateTime, var1, var2
3: DateTime, var1, var2
....

At each DateTime, I'd like to find the value of var1-var1 at the previous DateTime, and var2-var2 at the previous DateTime, and plot those.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Since you didnt provide a dataset I created one. Comments in the code should explain what each step does. Feel free to post questions in the comments.

```
df <- data.frame(time=c("2016-05-03","2016-05-04","2016-05-05"),start=c(5,4,2),end=c(2,6,3))
library(dplyr)
#get dataframe with each row minus the previous row
df<-mutate(df, diff.end= end-lag(end),diff.start= start-lag(start))
#convert the date string to a date object
dates<-format(as.Date(df$time),format="%Y-%m-%d")
#create dataframe with just the data we want to plot
df<-cbind(df$diff.start,df$diff.end)
colnames(df)<-c("starting.diff","ending.diff")
#make the dataframe a time series object
timeseriesobj<-xts(df,order.by=as.Date(dates))
timeseriesobj
#create the dygraph
dygraph(timeseriesobj)
#note that the first point doesnt get plotted because its starting and ending values are NA
```

Code output when run:

```
> df <- data.frame(time=c("2016-05-03","2016-05-04","2016-05-05"),start=c(5,4,2),end=c(2,6,3))
> library(dplyr)
> #get dataframe with each row minus the previous row
> df<-mutate(df, diff.end= end-lag(end),diff.start= start-lag(start))
> #convert the date string to a date object
> dates<-format(as.Date(df$time),format="%Y-%m-%d")
> #create dataframe with just the data we want to plot
> df<-cbind(df$diff.start,df$diff.end)
> colnames(df)<-c("starting.diff","ending.diff")
> #make the dataframe a time series object
> timeseriesobj<-xts(df,order.by=as.Date(dates))
> timeseriesobj
           starting.diff ending.diff
2016-05-03            NA          NA
2016-05-04            -1           4
2016-05-05            -2          -3
> #create the dygraph
> dygraph(timeseriesobj)
> #note that the first point doesnt get plotted because its starting and ending values are NA
```